# Data is not inserted into the database using visual C# 2010 using SQL commands

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, connection

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();

        con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=YUVV-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=barcode;Integrated Security=True";
        con.Open();

        //MessageBox.Show("connection open");

        SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter();
        //ada.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from barcode", con);
        ada.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
        ada.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO barcode (bcd) " +
    "VALUES (@bcd)", con);
        ada.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@bcd", SqlDbType.NChar, 20,"bcd").Value = textBox1.Text;
        ada.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select bcd from barcode", con);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ada.Fill(ds, "barcode");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    }
```

Comment: You're **retrieving** data from the database here, using `ada.Fill()` - I don't see any inserts or updates happening in your code.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options for amending your code as follows (after `con.Open()`):

```
ada.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@bcd", SqlDbType.NChar, 20,"bcd").Value = textBox1.Text;
//add this line
//without it you are never executing your `InsertCommand`.
ada.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

ada.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select bcd from barcode", con);
...
```

Alternatively you can use a `SqlCommand` like so:

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO barcode (bcd) VALUES (@bcd)", con))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@bcd", SqlDbType.NChar, 20,"bcd").Value = textBox1.Text;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter();
//ada.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from barcode", con);
ada.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;

ada.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select bcd from barcode", con);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ada.Fill(ds, "barcode");
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

I'd also recommend using a `using` statement around your `SqlConnection` and `SqlDataAdapter` instances to ensure all resources are correctly disposed of.

Comment: @marc_s I see. I had assumed as `InsertCommand` is a `SqlCommand` it could still be used to fire commands (to be honest I've never used the `SqlDataApdater` class in this way). In that case I'll update the answer.

Comment: Sorry my bad - I had missed that first insert statement inside the `using` - that's a proper `INSERT` statement, of course!